# Axys 3.0 Report Writing Language

Tags: reporting

Just started a new job and have to use this very difficult and outdated reporting software Axys. This thing doesn't even use a database, it's based on a flat file system.

Anyway I've been asked to adjust a few reports in Axys but haven't got a clue were to start. The Report Writing Language is like an amalgamation of (php, java, and cobalt) and not very nice to look at let alone make any scene of.

Was wondering if anyone here has any experience of this reporting soft ware as there isn't much documentation out there on it.

I just have to add in a few subtotal areas etc.

Here's a sample of the code to show you what I mean:

```
else
    .#~9:face~$35:fname#~2_tmp3#~2_dtmp3#~2:llpri0#~2_dtmp7#~2_tmp7#~2_dtmp2#~2_dtmp6#~2_tmp10\n
  if $:isbond "y" =*
    .~~~$:bdesc\g
  goto h end of row eval a
if $:mature "y" =$ $:iscash "n" =$ &
  $_clip1 $<25:snmb
  #_tmp3 #_dtmp3 #:adun #:valf * /
  #subb4 #subb4 #_dtmp3 +~
  #subb6 #subb6 #_dtmp7 +~
  #_tmp7 #_dtmp2 #:adun #:valf * /
;  .#_tmp7 #_dtmp2 #:adun #:valf * / \n
  #subb8 #subb8 #_dtmp2 +~
  #subb9 #subb9 #_dtmp6 +~
  #_tmp10 #_dtmp5 #sub023 / 100 *
  #subb14 #subb14 #_dtmp2 +~
  #subb15 #subb15 #_dtmp3 +~
  #subb16 #subb16  #_zero #_dtmp3 $:zeromv "y" =$ ? +~
  #subb17 #subb17  #_zero #_dtmp2 $:zeromv "y" =$ ? +~
  #subb19 #subb19 #_dtmp6 +~
  #subb20 #subb20 #_dtmp7 +~
  #subb21 #subb21 #_dtmp4 +~
  #subb22 #subb22 #_dtmp5 +~
  #subb23 #subb23 #_dtmp5 +~
  #subb31 #_zero
  #subb35 #subb35 #_dtmp7 +~
  #subb39 #subb39 #_dtmp6 +~
  if $nosymb "n" =*
    .#~9:face~$_clip1~$35:fname#~2_tmp3#~2_dtmp3#~2:llpri0#~2_dtmp7#~2_tmp7#~2_dtmp2#~2_dtmp6#~2_tmp10\n
  else
    .#~9:face~$35:fname#~2_tmp3#~2_dtmp3#~2:llpri0#~2_dtmp7#~2_tmp7#~2_dtmp2#~2_dtmp6#~2_tmp10\n
  if $:isbond "y" =*
    .~~~$:bdesc\g
  goto h end of row eval a
if $:mature "y" =$ $:isbond "y" =* $:iscurr "y" =*  $:iscash "y" =* | $:vrs "y" =* &|  &
  #_dtmp0 #::llai0
  #_dtmp1 #::rrai0
  $_clip1 $<25:snmb
  #subb4 #subb4 #_dtmp3 +~
  #subb6 #subb6 #_dtmp7 +~
  #subb8 #subb8 #_dtmp2 +~
  #subb9 #subb9 #_dtmp6 +~
  #_tmp10 #_dtmp5 #sub023 / 100 *
  #subb11 #subb11 #_dtmp1 +~
  #subb12 #subb12 #_dtmp0 +~
  #subb14 #subb14 #_dtmp2 +~
  #subb15 #subb15 #_dtmp3 +~
  #subb16 #subb16  #_zero #_dtmp3 $:zeromv "y" =$ ? +~
  #subb17 #subb17  #_zero #_dtmp2 $:zeromv "y" =$ ? +~
  #subb19 #subb19 #_dtmp6 #_dtmp1 +~ +~
  #subb20 #subb20 #_dtmp7 #_dtmp0 +~ +~
  #subb21 #subb21 #_dtmp4 +~
  #subb22 #subb22 #_dtmp5 +~
  #subb23 #subb23 #_dtmp5 #_dtmp1 +~ +~
  #subb31 #_zero
  #subb35 #subb35 #_dtmp7 +~
  #subb39 #subb39 #_dtmp6 +~
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you know who created the software, and then bother them to give you some kind of developer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the best way to understand Advent's replang is to generate/modify a new/existing report with the Report Writer (repwiz32.exe) and analyze the diff between the old & new files.  The language is more like perl than anything else.

Here's the link to the latest ('14.2) Rep Lang PDF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h17kpk86nuld16a/AdventReplang14.2.pdf?dl=0

Good luck.